# que libreria se debe importar para grafo desde la matriz de adyacencia,

Tags: networkx

cuando intento correr el codigo

## definimos el grafo desde la matriz de adyacencia

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(matriz_distancias)

y al momento de correrlo me marca error
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_numpy_matrix'

Comment: 1) Preguntas y respuestas deben que ser en ingles. 2) La funcion se llama `nx.from_numpy_array` en las ultimas versiones de networkx.